# How to check if complex number is a whole number

Tags: python, sympy, complex-numbers

Given a value numerical value `x`, you can just do this `float(x).is_integer()` to check if it's an integer. Is there a way to do this for complex numbers?

I'm trying to use list comprehension to take only the integer roots of a polynomial over a finite field which are integers.

```
[r for r in solve(f,domain=FiniteField(p)) if float(r).is_integer()]
```

but if the solve function returns complex roots, this doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to either: check if a given (possibly complex number) is an integer OR know if there's a SymPy function to get the roots of a polynomial over a finite field which are integers?

Comment: You mean just check the real part for integerness and ignore the imaginary part?

Comment: Can you please show some example inputs and outputs so that we can understand the problem better?

Comment: BTW, the `domain=FiniteField(p)` argument to `solve` doesn't appear to do anything at all.

Comment: Try this: `[irred for irred in factor(f, modulus=p).as_ordered_factors() if degree(irred) == 1]`.  This gives you just the linear factors of a monic polynomial `f` modulo `p`, and from those you should be able to extract the roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`ground_roots`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html?highlight=ground_roots#sympy.polys.polytools.ground_roots) function along with the `modulus` keyword argument. This returns the roots modulo `p`, with multiplicities. Here's an example:

```
>>> from sympy import Symbol, ground_roots
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> f = x**5 + 7*x + 1
>>> p = 13
>>> ground_roots(f, modulus=p)
{-5: 1, 4: 2}
```

That says that the roots of `poly` modulo `13` are `-5` and `4`, with the root `4` having multiplicity `2`.

By the way, it looks to me as though complex numbers are a [red herring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring) here: the roots of an integral polynomial over a finite field can't naturally be regarded as complex numbers.  The call to `solve` in your original post is ignoring the `domain` argument and is simply giving algebraic numbers (which *can* reasonably be interpreted as complex numbers) as its results, which is probably why you ended up looking at complex numbers. But these aren't going to help when trying to find the roots modulo a prime `p`.

Comment: Darn it.  I just found the `ground_roots` function.  Now I have to throw most of this answer away.

Comment: (Reluctantly) deleted the floundering around with the `factor` function.  It worked, but `ground_roots` is much more direct.

Comment: Yes, that's what I suspected about the complex roots, but I wasn't sure how to specify the domain correctly! But this is exactly what I need, so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`float.is_integer(z.real)` tells you if the real part is integer

Comment: @Mohit Jain yes it does answer the OP's question, which was *"Is there a way to do [check if the real part is an integer] for complex numbers?"*

Comment: Sorry my bad. In that case I would suggest to add a brief description.

Comment: @MohitJain. It already has a brief description: *"tells you if the real part is integer"*. What on earth? Would you please delete your comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if imaginary part is zero, you can do this:

```
In [17]: a=2 + 2j

In [18]: bool(a.imag)
Out[18]: True

In [19]: b=2 + 0j

In [20]: bool(b.imag)
Out[20]: False
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension as in your original question, one could do:

```
roots = [complex(r) for r in solve(f, domain=FiniteField(p))]
int_roots = [z.real for z in roots if z.real.is_integer() and not z.imag]
```